# CDH 6.2 - add new host error: dpkg-query: no packages found matching cloudera-manager-agent

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am tring to add a new host.

but it fails with this message at the end "***dpkg-query: no packages found matching cloudera-manager-agent***"

The following is the "*/tmp/scm_prepare_node.vQZe0yDf/scm_prepare_node.log*" on the failing host:

```
using SSH_CLIENT to get the SCM hostname: 10.4.34.22 37758 22
opening logging file descriptor
###CLOUDERA_SCM### SCRIPT_START
###CLOUDERA_SCM### TAKE_LOCK
BEGIN flock 4
END (0)
###CLOUDERA_SCM### DETECT_ROOT
effective UID is 1000
BEGIN which pbrun
END (1)
BEGIN sudo -S id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
END (0)
Using 'sudo ' to acquire root privileges
###CLOUDERA_SCM### DETECT_DISTRO
BEGIN grep 'Ubuntu' /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
END (0)
BEGIN grep DISTRIB_CODENAME /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
END (0)
BEGIN echo DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial | cut -d = -f 2
xenial
END (0)
###CLOUDERA_SCM### DETECT_SCM
BEGIN host -t PTR 10.4.34.22
Host 22.34.4.10.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
END (1)
BEGIN which python
/usr/bin/python
END (0)
BEGIN python -c 'import socket; import sys; s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET); s.settimeout(5.0); s.connect((sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))); s.close();' 10.4.34.22 7182
END (0)
BEGIN which wget
/usr/bin/wget
END (0)
BEGIN wget -qO- -T 1 -t 1 http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname && /bin/echo
END (4)
###CLOUDERA_SCM### REPO_INSTALL
Checking https://archive.cloudera.com/cm6/6.2.0/ubuntu1604/apt/dists/
Checking https://archive.cloudera.com/cm6/6.2.0/dists/
Using 
installing repository file /tmp/scm_prepare_node.vQZe0yDf/repos/ubuntu_xenial/cloudera-manager.list
repository file /tmp/scm_prepare_node.vQZe0yDf/repos/ubuntu_xenial/cloudera-manager.list installed
installing apt keys
BEGIN sudo apt-key add /tmp/scm_prepare_node.vQZe0yDf/customGPG
OK
END (0)
installing priority file /tmp/scm_prepare_node.vQZe0yDf/ubuntu_xenial
priority file /tmp/scm_prepare_node.vQZe0yDf/ubuntu_xenial installed
###CLOUDERA_SCM### REFRESH_METADATA
BEGIN sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Reading package lists...
END (0)
BEGIN sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Reading package lists...
END (0)
###CLOUDERA_SCM### PACKAGE_INSTALL cloudera-manager-agent
BEGIN sudo dpkg -l cloudera-manager-agent | grep -E '^ii[[:space:]]*cloudera-manager-agent[[:space:]]*'
dpkg-query: no packages found matching cloudera-manager-agent
END (1)
BEGIN sudo apt-cache show cloudera-manager-agent
E: No packages found
END (100)
cloudera-manager-agent must have Version=6.2.0 and Build=968826, exiting
closing logging file descriptor
```

Note that:

- both the master node and the new host node run ubuntu 16
- Public Cloudera Repository

Answer (score 0):

Can you try installing the Cloudera agent manually on each node(when the number of nodes are less):

```
$ sudo apt-get install cloudera-manager-agent cloudera-manager-daemons
```

On every cluster host, configure the Cloudera Manager Agent to point to the Cloudera Manager Server by setting the following properties in the **/etc/cloudera-scm-agent/config.ini**

```
$ sudo service cloudera-scm-agent start
```

**Make sure JAVA is installed in all the nodes**

For some reason the sources.list.d file becomes empty after running the manager on these nodes.